# Is it possible to revise the resolution to a merge conflict in git?

Tags: git, diff, gitkraken

I am working on a tex file together with a collaborator using git (using gitkraken).
We work on the same branch, and at some point there were some merge conflicts when one of us pushed our latest work onto that branch.
Since then we have continued working on this file, but we have realized that we would like to "redo" resolving the merge conflicts from a couple of commits back.

Is there a clean way to do this?

One thing I though of was to copy the version of the file in question (there is only one file of interest) and then just overwrite the current version of the file and then push that file onto the current branch, but I'm afraid this will overwrite some of the changes (that we'd like to keep) since the original conflict in question.
Another way could be to copy the old version that has some of the changes we'd like to keep and then use a diff tool to merge in selectively the things we'd like to change.

This last option is the best thing I could come up with. Is there a better way?

Comment: Seems that you have a problem in the *flow* or i.o.w. *process* how to do things in your collaborative work. For now the best solution is solely depends on this repository being *published* (do not mix with *public*) or not. If the latter is the case, `git rebase --interactive` perhaps helps.

Answer (score 3):

Every commit—including merge commits—simply holds a full and complete snapshot of *all* of your files.

Once you're collaborating with other people, it's usually not worth a lot of effort to go back and "fix" previous commits.  In fact, that's technically impossible: you can't change any existing commits.  What you end up doing is providing new-and-improved alternative commits, in place of the originals.  For instance, suppose:

```
...--I--J
         \
          M--N--O   <-- branch (HEAD)
         /
...--K--L
```

is the current situation, i.e., existing commits up through `J` and up through `L` got merged to make `M`, and you and they have since built `N` and `O` atop `M`.  You now discover that there's a "bug" in the snapshot stored in merge commit `M` due to some mis-resolution of conflicts.

The only way to make a corrected version of `M` is to make a new merge commit, `M'`.  (There are several ways of doing that.)  The result is:

```
...--I--J__
        |  \
        |   M--N--O   <-- branch
         \ /
          x
         / \
...--K--L---M'  <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

That is, bad merge `M` *still exists* even though you have now made new-and-improved merge `M'` on this new replacement branch `newbranch`.  You now need to copy `N` and `O` as well, to new-and-improved `N'` and `O'`:

```
...--I--J__
        |  \
        |   M--N--O   <-- branch
         \ /
          x
         / \
...--K--L---M'-N'-O'  <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

Now you need to have everyone—you and everyone else—*stop using* the old chain, `M-N-O` as found by name `branch`, and start using instead the *new* chain, `M'-N'-O'`.  In *your* Git, you can erase the name `branch` and rename `newbranch` to `branch`.  In *their* Git, they'll have to do the same thing.  Everyone must change over at the same time.  This tends to be a lot of work.

It's usually better to just admit that the past has a bug in it.  Make a new commit atop `O` that fixes the problem:

```
...--I--J
         \
          M--N--O--P   <-- branch (HEAD)
         /
...--K--L
```

Everyone can pick up new commit `P` as usual and just keep working as usual.  Sure, commits `M-N-O` have bad snapshots ... but so what?  Bad stuff happens all the time; version control is not about preventing bad stuff, but rather about letting you correct it.  You've corrected it.

Comment: Making a new commit P is in fact what I was planning on doing. My question is really: Is there an efficient and clean way to create P?

Comment: Check out commit `O` (`git checkout branch`), edit, commit. You probably know what to fix already. If you want to re-perform merge `M` to find things to fix, though: check out either commit `J` or `L` (by hash ID, as a detached HEAD, or attach a new branch name). Run `git merge <hash>` on the other of the two commits. Perform the merge, resolve conflicts, and commit: you have now made merge `M'`. Run `git diff <hash-of-M> HEAD` to see what you resolved differently this time. Save the diff, check out commit `O`, and apply the patch (`git apply`).